Direction of force by fluid on convergent nozzle
If a convergent nozzle is placed at the end of a pipe, then, since mass must enter and exit the nozzle at the same rate in the steady state, the exit velocity is greater than the entrance velocity. This implies that the force $F$ on the nozzle due to the water is backward i.e. $$F=\dot{P}_{in}-\dot{P}_{out}<0$$
I cannot rationalize this intuitively as the water clearly pushes onto forward the edges of the nozzle as it is forced into a smaller diameter. How, then, can the force on the nozzle be backward

Yes the pressure higher up-stream and so the water tends to want to blow the nozzle off the hose. The reaction  force still tends to blow you backwards, but, just like a rocket engine,  the reaction  force is given by the area of the exit nozzle multiplied by  difference between the upstream pressure on the wall of the hose times and the  pressure  at  the exit hole in nozzle which is atmospheric.
